# Which part of the sentence does 関連してる modify?

Tags: grammar

> 鮫島は携帯電話 {けいたいでんわ} を取りだして、『四凶 {しきょう}』を調べている様子だった。
>   「……パッと調べてもわからねぇことだらけだが、関連してる四神とかいうのに名前ぐらい知ってるのがあるな。玄武 {げんぶ} やら朱雀 {すざく}やら。『四凶』ってのと関係あるのか？」
>
> 関連してる四神とかいうのに名前ぐらい知ってるのがあるな

As far as I understand, it should mean something along the lines of "I at least know names related to Four Symbols", however I'm not sure, because 関連してる is positioned before 四神 and therefore should modify it. But in this case it doesn't make much sense to me as I don't get to what exactly 四神 is related to.

And if my interpretation is correct, shouldn't it be like?

> 四神 {ししん}とかいうのに関連してる名前ぐらい知ってるのがあるな。

Comment: Sorry, added context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"四神" is, as you know, Four Symbols in China, but your translation is a bit wrong. Indeed we can't figure out what they are related to from that sentence. Maybe some words are omitted before "関連してる" like:
(この事件に)関連してる四神とかいうのに名前ぐらい知ってるのがあるな。 
 
I've heard about the names of "四神" related to (this incident). 
Also, the sentence "四神とかいうのに関連してる名前ぐらい知ってるのがあるな。" is something ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But if 関連してる really modifies 四神, then what meaning would に have ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't explain how "に" works here.  According to added context, it says "(四凶と)関連してる四神とかいうのに名前ぐらい知ってるのがあるな。" meaning "I've heard about the names of "四神" related to "四凶"."

Comment: Oh, I see. I just got confused by the fact that a character says he heard the names of 四神 related to 四凶, but in the following sentence asks if there is any connection between them (looks like it's in the sense of seeking confirmation) and by the に usage. Thanks again!